# Different import variable has different id in Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following source structure:

```
module/data/__init__.py
module/data/repo.py
module/__init__.py
module/test.py
```

And the following code:

**repo.py**

```
goods = {}
```

**test.py**

```
from data import repo as repo1
from module.data import repo as repo2

print id(repo1.goods)
print id(repo2.goods)
```

## output

139783188635272

139783188649136

it seems that they are different variables; What really happened?

use absolute imports can avoid this problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @MattDMo I think Jonas is asking why the ids of what're supposedly the same object are different especially since they're the same when using absolute imports (according to OP).

Comment: yes, they are the same object. but seems in different name space. I just want to know why, or relative import is not recommended to use? thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that `repo1` and `repo2` are different modules, so they are in different namespaces.

```
print globals()

#Produces the below output (formatted for readability)


{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>,
'__file__': '/home/zhou/PycharmProjects/test_import/module/test.py',
'repo2': <module 'module.data.repo' from '/home/zhou/PycharmProjects/test_import/module/data/repo.pyc'>,
'__package__': None,
'repo1': <module 'data.repo' from '/home/zhou/PycharmProjects/test_import/module/data/repo.pyc'>,
'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: True, but I guess the bigger problem is that you are mixing package-imports and normal imports. Do not use normal import (`import foo`) when using packge imports (`from module.data import bar`)